# Detect end of message for socket communication PHP

Tags: php, sockets, newline

I have small HTTP server script that receives HTTP client requests and replies. I need to detect when there is \r\n\r\n type of ending. This happens when we have an input like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: test.com
Connection: close
```

I need to stop reading after the "Connection: close" double return hit. I tried with strpos and other string functions, but it is not working. Any hints to detect this kind of string ending in PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you reading data from the socket and then checking for \r\n\r\n?  `strpos($response, "\r\n\r\n")` will work for that, but you have to be looking at the entire buffer.  Also, its possible the connection won't be close in which case that header isn't set, and it also isn't guaranteed to be the last header before \r\n\r\n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that specific protocol you can just look for empty lines with:

```
 if (!strlen(trim($line))) {
```

Actually you should be looking for `\r\n` (and `\n` for buggy clients), but other combinations are unlikely to occur. So anything with just whitespace is not a valid header line anymore.